# string.find() isn't returning a -1 when it finds nothing in c++

Tags: c++, string, find

I am a student learning c++ and using geany and namespace std. 
I have some code that is giving me problems concerning string.find(), it returns large numbers for some reason when I would expect it to return -1.

```
string sentence [100];
cout << "Enter a sentence: \n";

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    cin >> sentence [i];
    if (sentence[i].find ('-') >0)
    {
        hyphenated ++;
        cout << "found a hyphen at "<< sentence[i].find('-') << " in word " << i << endl;
    }

}
```

When I input words with hyphens, it returns the correct index, however when I input words without hyphens, I get this number: 18446744073709551615

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`std::string::find(...)` and its sister functions do not return `-1` when the string or character isn't found. they return `std::string::npos`.

You should check the return value of `std::string::find` against `std::string::npos` to assert that your find succeeded.

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    cin >> sentence [i];
    auto pos = sentence[i].find('-');
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
    {
        hyphenated ++;
        cout << "found a hyphen at "<< pos << " in word " << i << endl;
    }

}
```

---

Techinally [`std::string::npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) is a `static` and `const` member of `std::string::size_type` defined to be `-1`, but because `-1` is converted to an unsigned type, the value becomes the largest positive integer `std::string::size_type` can represent

Comment: `npos` is defined as -1, but of type `size_type` which is an unsigned number. Hence the huge value the OP is seing.

Answer (score 0):

It returns string::npos, a constant, when the character is not found, not -1 in C++.

Here's the relevant documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/